# Triple Integral Volume Question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The question asks for the triple integral of $e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} dV$

where $D$ is a sphere of radius $4$.

The answer that I came up with is $2(1-e^{-64})$.

However, I am not confident in this answer as the exponent is negative.

The next question asks to find the mass of ball with radius 4 centered at origin with density of $8 e^{-p^3}$. So it does seem my answer makes sense.

Could I just double 8 to get the mass? Meaning mass would be $16(1-e^{-64})$?

Comment: Do you mean for the integrand to be $\frac12\exp{\left[(-x^2+y^2+z^2)^3\right]}$ or $\exp{\left[\frac{(-x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}{2}\right]}$? They way you have it written, the order of operations isn't exactly clear.

Comment: The edit should make it more clear.

Comment: Are you sure the problem has been transcribed correctly? Do you mean for the sign in front of $x^2$ to be negative while the signs in front of the $y$ and $z$ terms are positive?

Comment: Your answer is a positive value which is fine. However I have not carried out the calculations.

Comment: I am 99% sure that the integral was meant to have $-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}$, not $(-x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}$.

Comment: Yes the negative is actually outside of the parentheses. I edited the post to reflect.

Answer (score 4):

This integral lends itself to evaluation in spherical coordinates, which probably shouldn't come as a shock. After transforming to spherical coordinates, the triple integral is immediately separable into a product of three one-dimensional integrals:

$$\begin{align}
\iiint_{D}\mathrm{d}V\,e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\sin{\theta}\int_{0}^{4}\mathrm{d}r\,r^2\,e^{-r^3}\\
&=4\pi\int_{0}^{4}\mathrm{d}r\,r^2\,e^{-r^3}\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{3}\left[1-e^{-64}\right].
\end{align}$$

---

Next, to calculate the mass of the ball with density $f(r)=8e^{-r^3}$, we simply calculate the volume integral of the density function:

$$\begin{align}
M
&=\iiint_{D}\mathrm{d}V\,f(r)\\
&=\iiint_{D}\mathrm{d}V\,8e^{-r^3}\\
&=8\,\iiint_{D}\mathrm{d}V\,e^{-r^3}.
\end{align}$$

Now, the integral $\iiint_{D}\mathrm{d}V\,e^{-r^3}$ is *exactly* what you calculated above. So, $8$ times that integral will give you the mass:

$$M=8\cdot\frac{4\pi}{3}\left[1-e^{-64}\right]=\frac{32\pi}{3}\left[1-e^{-64}\right].$$

Comment: So I did the integral right. In each case of spherical, you add the 4pi/3? In the case of the second question, would the answer just be 4pi/3 16[1-e^-64]?

Comment: @reed20 No. You multiplied by $8$ incorrectly. See the added information in my edit.